# Сыпятся ошибки при запуске rails -s

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Собственно макбук приказал долго жить поэтому поставил на старый бук, Linux Mint

Установил Ruby и собственно Rails

Проект создается хорошо, но после попытки запуска получаем следующее (Огромное кол-во строк)

```
    rails aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:12:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:12:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:12:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/andrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/home/andrey/railsnew/omg/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Собственно код в гем ФАЙЛЕ

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      nio4r (~> 1.2)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
    activerecord (5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (7.1.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    puma (3.6.0)
    rack (2.0.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.0.1)
      actioncable (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.1)
      activerecord (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.2.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    spring (1.7.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (~> 1.2)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.3.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      debug_inspector
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  puma (~> 3.0)
  rails (~> 5.0.0, >= 5.0.0.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А вы не пугайтесь! Читайте, осознавайте. Обратите внимание на эту строчку. Она почти в самом верху, до неё надо было прочитать не так уж и много.

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

Идём по ссылке, видим список:

> ExecJS supports these runtimes:
>
> - [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) - Google V8   embedded within Ruby
> - [therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino) - Mozilla   Rhino embedded within JRuby
> - [Duktape.rb](https://github.com/judofyr/duktape.rb) - Duktape JavaScript interpreter
> - [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
> - Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X
> - [Microsoft Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx) (JScript)
> - [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)
> - [mini_racer](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer) - Google V8   embedded within Ruby

Вам нужен любой из них. В настоящее время популярны в основном:

- **Node.js** (потому что фронт-энду он всё равно частенько нужен)
- **therubyracer** (потому что это, кхм, просто гем, поставил и понёсся)

Comment: Спасибо ) Установил отдельно Node.js - и вуаля, все заработало, но столкнулся с другим интересным багом. 

Открываю новый терминал, любые функции rails 
rails new 
rails s  
rake routes 
 
Просто сыпятся и ругаются на отсутствие доступа к rubygems.rb

Comment: @Andrew Вот этого я уже не знаю, как вы могли добиться. Разве что поломали что-то в файлах RVM. Весьма вероятно, переустановка Ruby это решит, если нет -- надо копать.

Comment: переустановка полностью rvm, ruby - не помогло, результат тот же...  
Имеем вот это 

<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Comment: @Andrew тогда задавайте вопрос отдельно. И посмотрите, не сработают ли решения [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2896485/2076787).